# How to Detect Whether a Page is Refreshed or Closed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to detect whether a page is refreshed or closed. If the page is refreshed then I have to count the number of time it is refreshed.I am using the following code:

```
var count = 1;    
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){
        if(sessionStorage.getItem('retainedCount')){
        count = sessionStorage.getItem('retainedCount');
        }
        alert('The number of time that the page has refreshed is   : '+count);
        count++;
        sessionStorage.setItem('retainedCount',count);
    });
```

Its working fine when I press F5 or browser refresh button. But it is also executing when the page is closed which I don't want. Is there a way to explicitly detect the closing of a window?

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4DD6j/

Thanks !!

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, the `.on()` method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers

Comment: This gonna help you a lot... http://forums.asp.net/t/1537364.aspx?How+to+know+if+the+user+exit+or+close+browser+not+refresh+or+move+to+another+page+  just check the answer in javascript what there you after...